# How to Scale Image in Fabric Js Dynamic Pattern

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've a object which has a fill of Fabric Dynamic Pattern
I'm listening to double click event on the object. When double click event triggered, I am adding a new image object on the screen to give user the functionality to adjust the image inside pattern.
Here is my code for double click event.

```js
const activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
const fill = activeObject.fill;
if (fill && fill instanceof fabric.Pattern) {
 fabric.Image.fromURL(fill.src, function (img) {
                img.set({
                  scaleX: 1 / 1,
                  scaleY: 1 / 1,
                  for: "pattern_fill",
                  left: svgMask.left,
                  top: svgMask.top,
                  opacity: 0.4,
                });
                const W = svgMask.getScaledWidth();
                const H = svgMask.getScaledHeight();
                const K = H / W;
                const w = img.getScaledWidth();
                const h = img.getScaledHeight();
                const k = h / w;
                k < K ? img.scaleToHeight(H) : img.scaleToWidth(W);
                canvas.add(img);
                canvas.setActiveObject(img);
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
              });
}
```

I'm listening to another event that is "before:selection:cleared".

```
const activeObject=canvas.getActiveObject();
      if (activeObject.for==="pattern_fill") {
        await updateImagePattern(
          svgMask,
          activeObject
        );
        canvas.remove(activeObject);
        canvas.requestRenderAll();
      }
```

Is there any possible way to adjust the image in the fabric pattern.?

I'm expecting that image in the fill of the object will get scaled according to the dbl click image.